Difference between $y = |x|$ and $|y| = x$
The Modulus function or the Absolute Value function is generally taught at the pre-university level. Here's a question to test your basics.

Let $y = |x|$ and $|y| = x$ be two functions. The first is a function in 'x', the latter is a function in 'y'. The difference is understood better when we plot their graphs.

Consider $y = |x|$,
$$y = |x| \Rightarrow y = \pm x$$
$$y = +x$$ or, $$y = -x$$
Similarly, consider |y| = x,
$$|y| = x \Rightarrow \pm y = x$$
$$ +y = x \Rightarrow y = +x$$ or, $$-y = x \Rightarrow y = -x$$
Therefore, both functions are algebraically the same.
This, however, is completely false.
What do you think could be wrong with the approach?
{Hint: Piecewise functions}

$y=|x|\iff y\ge0\wedge x^2=y^2$; $x=|y|\iff x\ge0\wedge x^2=y^2$

When we say $y = |x|$, we mean to say,
$$y = +x, x>0$$ $$y = -x, x<0$$
This is called as a piecewise function, i.e., a function that is defined on sequence of intervals. Now, let's plot the graph of the above function. We can understand this better if we take certain 'inputs' and find out their 'outputs'. For example, take a number $x$, such that $x>0$, say $5$. This $x$ is our 'input'. According to the above function, if $x>0$, then $y = +x$. Here, $y$ is our 'output'. Therefore, if we plug-in the value of $x$ in $y = +x$, we obtain $y = +5$. Similarly, if we take other values of $x$ such that $x>0$, we obtain a straight line in the first quadrant. Similarly, take any $x$ such that $x<0$, say $-5$. The 'output' in this case will be $y = -(-5) = +5$. If we take a few more values of $x$ such that $x<0$, we will obtain a straight line in the second quadrant, but with negative slope. The graph of this function is symmetrical about the y-axis.

Let's take $|y| = x$,
$$+y = x, y>0 \Rightarrow x = +y, y>0$$ $$-y = x, y<0 \Rightarrow x = -y, y<0$$
Here, we need to understand that $x$ is the'output' and $y$ is the 'input'. The graph of this function will be symmetrical about x-axis.
Many-a-times, while we solve mathematics, we tend to do mistakes such as cancelling the $x$ while solving quadratic equations, $\sqrt{25} = \pm 5$ instead of $\sqrt{25} = 5$, $y=|x|$ as $y =\pm x$ without defining it piecewise. Therefore, it is important to carefully understand and not miss such details while practicing on pen and paper.

I'd suggest waiting a bit, before posting your answer, to give other people a chance to do it. However, +1 for the question


In $y = |x|$ you can see that if we replace x by -x then value of y not change which implies that their graph will be like even function so if you make the graph for x > 0 then reflect the graph in y-axis.

2)$|y| = x$ here y must have positive value so if x is negative then y will have no solution which implies graph cannot exist in 2nd and 3rd quadrant.
So if X is positive then y will be have 2 values as K and -K so you have to draw y=X in 1st quadrant and reflect it in X-axis .
This is how you can understand the difference between  $y = |x|$ and $|y| = x$
